# Options for communication between nodejs server and PHP website

Tags: php, node.js, communication

So far I used websockets to communicate between nodejs and php.
I created a websocket server in nodejs that is listening on some custom port.

Then in the php script I used `stream_socket_client()` and related functions to connect as client.
Then whenever I wanted something from the server I would send a message and expect a response with the data (as json). Then it would build the html to display that data to the user.

This works, however it does not seem natural and I was wondering if there are better options. Websockets are intended for the web as the name implies, but I am using it for local server and script

I should mention that the server needs to be able to communicate with multiple clients at the same time, because a website can have multiple visitors. The nodejs websocket modules offer this capability. But it does not need to keep connections alive, because the php script only does its thing and stops.

Comment: Why do you need PHP? Node.js can anything PHP does, much faster and probably better.

Comment: I was going to say similar... why have you got two server-side languages on the go, seemingly as part of the same application? Seems like a bit of an architectural nightmare.

Comment: moving completely to node its on the "todo" list. Unfortunately the client is hesitant so I need to take one step at a time. First I am moving file i/o and db to node, then eventually the html too

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore why you use both `Node.js` and `PHP` (which may be the source of your bad feeling), and concentrate on RPC question.

While picking an RPC approach, you should consider and compare different things about each approach, see my checklist.

### Checklist

This helps me pick approaches.

Run-time:

- Speed
- Memory
- Stability

Development-time:

- Time
- Difficulty
- Testability and/or Debugability

### Conclusion

Having above said, as far as I understood, your current Web-Socket approach has fulfilled all of checklist, like:

Run-time:

- Speed: `localhost` connections take `0` mili-sec.
- Memory: around `2 MB` (freed after each request).
- Stability: Web-Sockets are globally used, and if anything is stable, then it's **local** Web-Socket.

Development-time:

- Time: It's already developed.
- Difficulty: It's well known.
- Testability and/or Debugability: Testable with both `PHPUnit` and/or whatever you use to test `Node.js` code.

> **Please stay with Web-Sockets,** because even if you develop some kind of custom protocol, it will break more than one point in shown checklist.